# XML serialisation. Avoid auto-escaping

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to include carage return and line feed characters into an XML.

So I'm tring to replace `\r\n` with `&#xD;&#xA;`... but in the output XML `&` character will be escaped and result is `&amp;#xD;&amp;#xA;`.

Is there any way to avoid auto-escaping for a single attribute? Or maybe there is another effective way to solve my problem?

Comment: Why did you find yourself needing to replace the \r\n?

Comment: this is a description field, which can be multiline. this field will be set in a configurator tool serialized into XML and then will be shown in an other tool. And the description must be shown as a multiline string.

Comment: Are you loosing the \r\n after the deserialization?

Comment: Not quite :) \r\n from XML file will be replaced with \n while deserialization and the whole text will be shown in a single line.

Comment: I think I got the problem. You are trying to replace the \r\n before the serialization, and obviously it will be escaped when serializing. But I still don't understand under what circumstances the \r\n becomes an \n. Are you serializing on one machine and deserializing on another? are you using different OSes? combining .net with mono? I did some tests and I can't reproduce this behavior with VS2012.

Comment: Yes, serialization and deserialization will be done on differen PCs. Anyway, this is documented in the MSDN: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx).

My currently solution:

Comment: My currently solution:
On serialisation - i'm using XmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling to add `&#xD;&#xA;` into attributes content.
On serialization - i'm using XmlTextReader.Normalization = false; to get `\r\n` for text node values....

It's not a perfect solution, but i don't know, how could i solve this troulbe in other way.

Comment: Have you tried with XmlSerializer? That's what I tried with and worked ok.